# What is meaning of "mustacheExpress().cache = null;"?

Tags: node.js, mustache

now I`m implementation a simple application using Node.js, mustache and when using mustacheExpress(), some tutorial says to code like,

```
const mustacheExpressInstance = mustacheExpress();
mustacheExpressInstance.cache = null;
```

I have no idea what it means and what it is for. 
nothing changed even marked this code out...

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation for Mustache Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache-express)

`const mustacheExpressInstance = mustacheExpress();`

This instantiates the mustache express into a variable

`mustacheExpressInstance.cache = null;`

This tells the object to not cache the file. I suggest you review the documentation and review Object Oriented concepts.